# Perform static method on type

Tags: swift

In my application I got a class which is called `A`. I have 2 classes (`B` and `C`) that inherit from this class.

The `Controller` class has a method `class func D(includeStored: Bool, completion: (results: [Controller]) -> Void)`.

This is a static method on the Controller class, my 2 subclasses **can** override this method, but it is not certain it does.

I would like to create an array with the **types** of my 2 subclasses in them, like this:

`var myTypes = [ B.self, C.self ]`

then I would like to execute the function `A` on those types, but I am not able to get this done.

What I have tried:

```
for item in myTypes {
    (item as A.self).D(false, completion: { (results) -> Void in
    });
}
```

This doesn't work. Also without the cast it (obviously) doesn't work, because then it is an AnyObject. Because it isn't an object, but a class I want to use I cannot cast it normally.

Also tried this, but this crashes, because it is trying to instantiate the type, but it is also a NSManagedObject, so it can't be instantiated this way (`item()`).

```
var myTypes: [A.Type] = [ B.self, C.self ];

for item in controllerClasses {
    var i = item();
    i.dynamicType.D(false, completion: { (results) -> Void in
        NSLog("Found: \(results.count)");
    });
}
```

Any pointers on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was easier than I thought. After I specified the type on the `myTypes` array, I could easily loop through them. Because it is a static method on the class, I did not need to instantiate it at all and I could just use it directly.

```
var myTypes: [A.Type] = [ B.self, C.self ];

for item in myTypes {
    item.D(false, completion: { (results) -> Void in
    });
}
```

Posted it as an answer, so for anyone that needs it in the future knows it is solved.